# jQuery awkward behaviour

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, jquery-selectors

I am trying to load a page throughout ajax, the whole page, and formating mine as it finds in the loaded one. Something of a practical exercise.

The result of the ajax call is a string containing the page's html.

To make it simple, I made an example, with a string containing something of a page itself.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .dv810 { height:810px; }            
        </style>
        <script src="Scripts/Ref/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sPage =
            +'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'
            + '\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'
            + '\n<head>'
            + '\n    <title>some test</title>'
            + '\n    <style type="text/css">'
            + '\n'
            + '\n    #dvMain { height:830px; }'
            + '\n'
            + '\n    </style>'
            + '\n</head>'
            + '\n<body>'
            + '\n    <div class="container_12 mainContainer">'
            + '\n        <div id="dvMain" class="dv810"></div>'
            + '\n        <br/>'
            + '\n    </div>'
            + '\n</body>'
            + '\n</html>';

            alert('#dvMain: ' + $('#dvMain', $(sPage)).css('height'));

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got this awkward behavior when trying to pull one's css property, like height:

- Firefox: #dvMain.height: 810px
- Chrome: #dvMain.height:
- IE8: #dvMain.height: 830px
- IE8 (with IEtester): #dvMain.height: 830px
- IE7 (with IEtester): #dvMain.height: 830px
- IE6 (with IEtester): #dvMain.height: 830px

As it seems:

- IE understands the css in the string, hell knows how (although that is a strange behaviour, I kinda like it, although I think I would not use it much),
- Firefox behaves as I think it would be accurate, gets the class from style in the rendered page,
- Chrome for my surprise, does not understand or don't relate it, uhn,.. well, just show nothing

  Does anyone knows why?

Comment: I think you have to close the second div: `<div id="dvMain" class="dv810">`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your varied results i think its a matter of dom processing time i wonder if the results are different by amending the code like so:

```
var $sPage = $(sPage);
alert('#dvMain: ' + $('#dvMain', $sPage).css('height'));
```

OR

```
$(sPage).ready(function(){
  alert('#dvMain: ' + $('#dvMain', $(sPage)).css('height'));
});
```